# Getting InvalidUseOfMatchersException in the Mockito

Tags: mockito

I have written this java method:

```
public int run(String jobName) {
}
```

And I have written this test code:

```
@Test
public void testBatchStatusUpdateWithOneCompleteStatus() {

    Set<BatchEntity> staleBatch = createStaleBatch();
    Set<Integer> activeBatch = createActiveBatch();


    when(batchRepository.findBatchIdByStateIn(
            (Arrays.asList(BatchStates.IN_PROGRESS,
                    BatchStates.INTENT_MARKED)))).thenReturn(staleBatch);
    when(listingRepository.findBatchId()).thenReturn(activeBatch);

    Assert.assertEquals(batchStatusUpdate.run(Mockito.any(String.class)), 1);
    Mockito.verify(batchRepository,Mockito.times(2)).save(Mockito.any(BatchEntity.class));
}
```

I am getting the below error when I run the

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:  Invalid use of argument matchers! 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded: at backgroundjob.BatchStatusUpdateTest.testBatchStatusUpdateWithOneCompleteStatus This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

I am getting this error when run method has the string argument. When I remove the string argument from the run method the test case is passed.

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.any()` creates a matcher, which is used when specifying a mock or when verifying calls with `Mockito.verify()`. They do not make sense as an argument to the method you are testing though. Your call should be changed to use an actual string, for example `Assert.assertEquals(batchStatusUpdate.run("some value"), 1);` instead of `Assert.assertEquals(batchStatusUpdate.run(Mockito.any(String.class)), 1);`